# How to implement a WrapBootstrap theme with CodeIgniter app?

Tags: codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I just bought a WrapBootstrap theme and am trying to insert it into my CodeIgniter application. I've never used WrapBootstrap and am not sure what the next step is because many of the files have ruby in them (they are .erb files).

Here's what I have found:

> First open your CSS files and replace all calls to `../img/` dir with plain `images/` to make pipeline find the graphic elements of the theme .
>
> For using the glyph you should create a new directory, fonts, to copy the glyph images there and expand the usable assets in application directory

Would I  be able to use it if I just copied the JavaScript, images, fonts and style sheets? (if I took all of the assets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

- Put the css, js, img and other asset folders into a folder called assets at the same level of Codeigniter's index.php. The files in these folders will be referenced from the html files like this (example with css): `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/style.css" />`
- The html files go to the views folder. You'll see that each html file is repeating a header and footer structure, so you can isolate this structure into a header and footer view. Normally, the header starts at the doctype declaration and ends at the main section (inside the body), and the footer starts at the end of the main section and ends with `</html>`. The rest (the main section), will be the view for that html. So you'll end up having: a header view, a view for each html file and a footer view.
- Header view: contains the `<head>` section and (normally) the nav bar. In the head section you reference the files (css, js, img) like I've written in the first point. Change the nav bar links to link to the correct controller (see last point).
- View for each html: contains the content of the page. At the top you should load the header view and at the bottom the footer view. You can name the view like the html file but be careful with the home (index.html). You'd better name it "home".
- Footer view: contains footer content and javascript files, which you should reference like the ones in the header.
- To call each view create a controller with the name of the html and load the view in the index function of the controller. For the home view use the default_controller in routes.php.

The .erb files are probably for backend processing of contact forms, so they're of no use if you use Codeigniter. You should replace them with controllers and models.